# Calculating datetime intervals taking into an account the current date

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a sub request which returns this:

```
item_id, item_datetime,        item_duration_in_days
1,       '7-dec-2016-12:00',    3                     
2,       '8-dec-2016-11:00',    4                    
3,       '20-dec-2016-05:00',   10                    
4,       '2-jan-2017-14:00',    50                    
5,       '29-jan-2017-22:00',   89
```

I want to get "item_id" which falls into "now()". For that the algorithm is:

```
  1) var duration_days = interval 'item_duration_in_days[i]'

  2) for the very first item: 
        new_datetime[i] = item_datetime[i] + duration_days

  3) for others: 
     - if a new_datetime from the previous step overlaps with the current item_datetime[i]:
        new_datetime[i] = new_datetime[i - 1] + duration_days

    - else:
        new_datetime[i] = item_datetime[i] + duration_days


  4) return an item for each iteration:
     {id, item_datetime, new_datetime}
```

That is, there'll be something like:

```
item_id  item_datetime    new_datetime
1         7 dec 2016       10 dec 2016
2        11 dec 2016       15 dec 2016
3        20 dec 2016       30 dec 2016
4         2 jan 2017       22 feb 2017   <------- found because now() == Feb 5
5        22 feb 2017       21 may 2017
```

How can I do that? I think it should be something like "fold" function. Can it be done via an sql request? Or will have to be an PSQL procedure for intermediate variable storage?

Or please give pointers how to calculate that.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "*new_datetime ... overlaps with current item_datetime*"? A timestamp (a single point in time) can not "overlap" with another timestamp. Ranges (from date - to date) can overlap

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, I mean, greater than.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly your task, you need recursive call. Function take first row  at `first` and process each next.

```
WITH RECURSIVE x AS (
   SELECT *
     FROM (
            SELECT item_id,
                   item_datetime,
                   item_datetime + (item_duration_in_days::text || ' day')::interval AS cur_end
              FROM ti
             ORDER BY item_datetime
             LIMIT 1
          ) AS first
   UNION ALL
   SELECT item_id,
          cur_start,
          cur_start + (item_duration_in_days::text || ' day')::interval
     FROM (
            SELECT item_id,
                   CASE WHEN item_datetime > prev_end THEN
                            item_datetime
                        ELSE
                            prev_end
                        END AS cur_start,
                   item_duration_in_days
              FROM (
                     SELECT ti.item_id,
                            ti.item_datetime,
                            x.cur_end + '1 day'::interval AS prev_end,
                            item_duration_in_days
                       FROM x
                       JOIN ti ON (
                               ti.item_id != x.item_id
                               AND ti.item_datetime >= x.item_datetime
                            )
                      ORDER BY ti.item_datetime
                      LIMIT 1
                    ) AS a
          ) AS a
) SELECT * FROM x;
```

Result:

```
 item_id |    item_datetime    |       cur_end       
---------+---------------------+---------------------
       1 | 2016-12-07 12:00:00 | 2016-12-10 12:00:00
       2 | 2016-12-11 12:00:00 | 2016-12-15 12:00:00
       3 | 2016-12-20 05:00:00 | 2016-12-30 05:00:00
       4 | 2017-01-02 14:00:00 | 2017-02-21 14:00:00
       5 | 2017-02-22 14:00:00 | 2017-05-22 14:00:00
(5 rows)
```

For seeing current job :

```
....
) SELECT * FROM x WHERE item_datetime <= now() AND cur_end >= now();

 item_id |    item_datetime    |       cur_end       
---------+---------------------+---------------------
       4 | 2017-01-02 14:00:00 | 2017-02-21 14:00:00
(1 row)
```

Comment: `I have a sub request which returns this:` how can I incorporate my query into your solution? Meaning, `ti` isn't a table in my example but you're treating it like a table.

Comment: although, I figure, I can create a view on my query, right?

Comment: Yes. This approach has disadvantages - if your table is very big you always calculate all results. I do not know whole system, but probably good way is to create two additional field - something like real_start, real_end.

Comment: I want to return the record #4, how can I do that?

Comment: ORDER BY item_datetime OFFSET 4 LIMIT 1

Comment: no, I mean `I want to get "item_id" which falls into "now()".`

Comment: спасибо гворю, помог дядьке, а то я ж уже старый, не соображу.